# Understanding the use of continuity and 'derivative change' in finding Green functions

Tags: derivatives, continuity, intuition, proof-explanation, greens-function

Below is a university question and the corresponding solution for which I do not understand small parts of:

`Question:`

> Show that the Green’s function for the range $x \ge 0$, satisfying $$\frac{\partial^2 G(x,z)}{\partial x^2}+G(x,z)=\delta(x-z)$$ with boundary conditions:$$G(x,z)=\frac{\partial G(x,z)}{\partial x}=0\quad\text{at}\quad x=0$$ is $$G(x,z)=\begin{cases}\cos z\sin x-\sin z\cos x, &\text{for} & x\gt z \\ 0 &\text{for} & x\lt z\end{cases}$$

`Solution:`

> For $x \ne z$ 
>   $$\frac{\partial^2 G(x,z)}{\partial x^2}+G(x,z)=0$$ with solution
>   $$G(x,z)=\begin{cases}A(z)\sin x+B(z)\cos x, &\text{for} & x\lt z \\ C(z)\sin x+D(z)\cos x &\text{for} & x\gt z\end{cases}$$
>   $$G(x=0,z)=0\implies B(z)=0$$ The derivative is (for $x\le z$)
>   $$\frac{\partial G(x,z)}{\partial x}=A(z)\cos x$$
>   Since this is zero at $x=0$, we conclude that $A(z)=0$. Hence, $$G(x,z)=0\qquad (x\lt z)$$
>   $\color{red}{\mathrm{For}}$ $\color{red}{x\gt z,}$ $\color{red}{\text{we use continuity of}}$ $\color{red}{G(x,z)}$ $\color{red}{\mathrm{at}}$ $\color{red}{x=z,}$ $\color{red}{\mathrm{ie.}}$
>   $$\color{red}{C(z)\sin z+D(z)\cos z=0\tag{1}}$$
>   $\color{red}{\text{The first derivative changes by}}$ $\color{red}{1,}$ $\color{red}{\text{so since}}$ $\color{red}{G(x,z)=0}$ $\color{red}{\text{for}}$ $\color{red}{x\lt z,}$
>   $$\color{red}{C(z)\cos z -D(z)\sin z=1\tag{2}}$$
>   We can eliminate $D$ (or $C$) from equations $(1)$ and $(2)$:
>   $$C(z)\cos z + C(z)\frac{\sin^2z}{\cos z}=1\tag{3}$$
>   Multiplying equation $(3)$ by $\cos z$ gives $$C(z)\cos^2 z+C(z)\sin^2 z=\cos z$$ and since $\cos^2 z+\sin^2 z=1$,
>   $$C(z)=\cos z$$ and we then find $$D(z)=-\sin z$$
>   Thus,
>   $$G(x,z)=\begin{cases}\cos z\sin x-\sin z\cos x, &\text{for} & x\gt z \\ 0 &\text{for} & x\lt z\end{cases}$$
>   $\fbox{}$

---

I understand everything apart from the part marked red;

Why is equation $\color{red}{(1)}$ equal to zero? What does this have to do with continuity?

Also equation $\color{red}{(1)}$ has products: $C(z)\sin z$ and $D(z)\cos z$ since $C(z)$ and $D(z)$ are both *functions* of $z$. So why isn't the product rule being used to yield $$C'(z)\sin z + C(z)\cos z + D'(z)\cos z -D(z)\sin z\text{?}$$

Why is it that the "first derivative changes by $1$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Green (or Green's) function satisfies the partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 G(x,z)}{\partial x^2}+G(x,z)=\delta(x-z) \tag 1$$

If $G$ were discontinuous at $x=z$, then its second derivative would result in a Dirac Doublet.  Inasmuch as the right-hand side of $(1)$ contains only the Dirac Delta, not the doublet, then $G$ is continuous.

Next, we integrate $(1)$ with respect to $x$ from $z-\epsilon$ to $z+\epsilon$, where $0<\epsilon<z$.  Exploiting the continuity of $G$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}\left(\frac{\partial^2 G(x,z)}{\partial x^2}+G(x,z)\right)\,dx&=\color{blue}{\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left.\frac{\partial G(x,z)}{\partial x}\right|_{x=z+\epsilon}^{x=z+\epsilon}}\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}\delta (x-z)\,dx\\\\
&=\color{blue}{1}
\end{align}$$

which results in the second boundary condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate a little on "Exploiting the continuity of $G$" as I need to know why $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}G(x,z)\to 0$ to get the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ equation in your answer? Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: The MVT guarantees that there exists a number $\xi \in (z-\epsilon,z+\epsilon)$ such that  $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}G(x,z)\,dx =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}G(\xi,x)\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}(1)\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}2\epsilon G(\xi,x)=0$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at the Mean Value Theorem now, is there anyway you could post a link that explains this information? Since the only form of the mean value theorem I know of is if $f(x)$ is defined and continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then there is at least one number $c$ in the interval $(a,b)$ (that is $a < c < b$) such that $f'(c)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ Thanks.

Comment: [Here is a link to the first mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals)

Comment: Please see my updated question and see if you can answer it. Thank again.

Comment: If $G(x<z,z)=0$ and $G(x,z)$ is continuous at $x=z$, then $G(z,z)=0$.  On the second issue, the partial derivatives are taken with respect to $x$, not $z$.

Comment: Hi, I have a very similar related question to this one regarding Green's functions. Since you answered this question well, I was wondering if you would mind having a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964885/what-is-the-meaning-of-discontinuity-in-greens-functions) also? Many thanks.

Comment: @MarkViola Hi, could you please explain why $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}\delta(x-z) dx=1$? I asked about this exact question on [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403134/continuity-of-greens-function-and-its-derivatives#comment10265638_2403134). My reason for asking is that according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim_%7B%5Cepsilon+%5Cto+0%7D%5Cint_%7Bz-%5Cepsilon%7D%5E%7Bz%2B%5Cepsilon%7D%5Cdelta%28x-z%29+dx) $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}\delta(x-z) dx$ never approaches 1 (from above or below).

Comment: @Electra Since the Dirac Delta has support $\{0\}$, then $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{z-\varepsilon}^{z+\varepsilon} \delta(x-z)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x-z)\,dx=1$$

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks, what is meant by "support $\{0\}$", and why is Wolfram-Alpha not giving the result of unity? I hope the link to that site is working okay. Regards.

Comment: @Electra See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#:~:text=With%20the%20%CE%B4%20distribution%2C%20one,support%20being%20%7B0%7D).). WA is not always correct.

Answer (score 2):

Those both follow from the **definition** of "Green's function".  Exactly what definition are you using?

You have $G(x, z)= 0$ for $x\lt z$ and $A(z)\cos(x)+ B(z) \sin (x)$ for $x\gt z$. It is required (part of the definition of "Green's function") that $G$ be continuous at $x = z$.  That means that the two 'parts' must match up at $x = z$.
The limit of $0$ as $x\to z$ is, of course, $0$.  Since $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are continuous functions, the limit of $A(z)\cos(x)+ B(z)\sin(x)$, as $x\to z$ is $A(z)\cos(z)+ B(z)\sin(z)$. So we must have $A(z)\cos(z)+ B(z)\sin(z)= 0$.

The fact that the derivatives must change by "$1$" is also part of the definition of the "Green's function" (more generally, if the differential equation has some function $a(x)$ multiplying the highest derivative, the derivative must change by $\dfrac{1}{a(z)}$ at $x = z$).

One of the simplest examples of a "Green's Function" is for a wire or string drawn taut between two points, $(0, 0)$ and $(L, 0)$, then "plucked".  The Green's function for that problem is the straight line from 
$(0, 0)$ to $(x, z)$ then another straight line from $(x, z)$ to $(L, 0)$.  The "broken line" is continuous where the two lines join and has fixed derivative there.  The actual wave motion is a sum of those broken line functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have only just started learning about Greens Functions and I haven't been given a formal definition yet, which is why I don't understand the solution in my post. Is there any chance you could provide a source that explains the definition of the Green Function as simply as possible? Thank you.