# Continuity of Green's function and its derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

We have a differential equation:

$$a_n(x)\frac{d^n y}{dx^n} + a_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1} y}{dx^{n-1}} + \dots + a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + a_0(x)y = \delta(x-z) $$

And this is satisfied by the Green's function $G(x,z)$. I've understood this far. However, I don't understand the following paragraph (Riley Hobson and Bence, Mathematical methods for Physics and Engineering):

[image]

My questions are as follows:

1. Why is $\frac{d^n G(x,z)}{dx^n}$ infinity at $x = z$?
2. Why are all the derivatives of order less than $n-1$ continuous?

Thank you.

Comment: A physics style of answer for the second question) If $\frac{d^{n}G}{dx^{n}}=\frac{d}{dz}\frac{d^{n-1}G}{dx^{n-1}}$ is infinity at point $z$, this implies that it is a derrivative of something discontinous, and as it is the derrivative of $\frac{d^{n-1}G}{dx^{n-1}}$ then $\frac{d^{n-1}G}{dx^{n-1}}$ must be discontinous. As $\frac{d^{n-1}G}{dx^{n-1}}$ is discontinous at $z$, but not infinity, it must be a derrivative of something continous, and it is a derrivative of $\frac{d^{n-2}G}{dx^{n-2}}$. Then $\frac{d^{k}G}{dx^{k}}$ are all continous for $k\in\{n-2, 0\}$.

Comment: at wich page of the book do you refer?

Comment: @ErikPillon page 512 of the 3rd edition

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but does anyone here know why the RHS of $(15.63)$ is one? According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim_%7B%5Cepsilon+%5Cto+0%7D%5Cint_%7Bz-%5Cepsilon%7D%5E%7Bz%2B%5Cepsilon%7D%5Cdelta%28x-z%29+dx) $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{z-\epsilon}^{z+\epsilon}\delta(x-z) dx$ is indeterminate.

Comment: The way I thought about it, we previously learnt integral over $\delta (x-z)$ is 1 in any interval containing $z$ and the book says this is the defining property of Delta function. Since $\epsilon$ is never $0$ in limiting case, interval always contains $z$.

Comment: Well Wolfram Alpha says otherwise, whether you let $\epsilon$ tend to zero from above or below the answer is never unity.